# display div dynamically on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm basically trying to replicate what you get on google images with a div appearing from an onClick event directly below the row of images containing the anchor that is clicked. I've found code for the show and hide methods which is pretty easy, as per below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#imageBox").hide("slow");
  });

  $('a').click(function(){
    $("#imageBox").show("slow");
    document.getElementById("displayImage").innerHTML = '<img src = "images/profiles/male-silhouette.jpg" style="margin:20px;" />';
  });

});
```

However I can't get around the div appearing wherever I place it in the HTML. For instance, in the code below the div with image and text will obviously always appear between the first and second lists, in the same place:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
 <div id="imageBox">
  <button id="hide" class="hButton">X Close</button>
  <p id="displayImage">&nbsp;</p>
 </div>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

After searching on Google and Stack Overflow I've not even come close to learning how to do this. Can anyone point to some open source code or a tutorial?

Comment: can you make it clear?

Comment: Can I make what clear?

Comment: where is $('a')  in html code??

Comment: @acl77 this is http://jsfiddle.net/ds2Lefq5/3/ with your code I can just close div .. how can I show it?

Comment: @acl77: i have added the answer.please check and tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is used to select elements and apply CSS to them and much more. You can learn a lot about jQuery on their website:
http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

The CSS is what provides the animation, with 'transitions'.
a box opening would change size (height for example) and you'd want to put a transition tag on the height property in the CSS of the particular div.

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

To learn jQuery, CSS, HTML and all, I recommend starting with W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have the placed the  `document.getElementById("displayImage").innerHTML` in the `$('a').click(function () {` where there is no anchor tag at all in the markup..
put the code inside the `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $("#imageBox").hide("slow");
    });
    document.getElementById("displayImage").innerHTML = '<img src = "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/7Ta/MBz/7TaMBzMqc.png" width="30px" height="30px" style="margin:20px;" />';
    $('a').click(function () {
        $("#imageBox").show("slow");

    });

});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y0881fjo/)

**NOTE**: can't understand your  `$('a').click(function () {` as i can't see any anchor tags in the markup.

**Change after your comment**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imageBox").hide();
    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $("#imageBox").hide("slow");
    });

    $('a').click(function () {
        $("#imageBox").show("slow");
        document.getElementById("displayImage").innerHTML = '<img src = "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/7Ta/MBz/7TaMBzMqc.png" width="30px" height="30px" style="margin:20px;" />';

    });

});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y0881fjo/1/)

Comment: Theat was me being sloppy when typing the example. I hve this - <li><a href="#" ><img class="imgThumb" src="images/pic.png" alt="" /></a></li>

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
 $('button funtion').on('click', function(event) {

            $('sample1').className;
            $('sample1').removeClassName('hidden');
            $('sample1').className;

            $('sample2').className;
            $('sample2').addClassName('hidden');
            $('sample2').className;

        });
```

attribute hide must be created in css

```
hidden {
visibility: hidden;
```

}

or you can searh for toogle class, this method invert the property

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

$("p").toggleClass("hidden");
});